# Pendulum tension force

Tags: physics, vectors, triangles, mathematical-physics

I realize this is physics related, although the problem is really about math so I thought it would be a good fit for this site.

[image]

My illustration is supposed to depict a pendulum and the forces acting on it (air resistance is neglected). The way I see it the gravitational force is (0, -mg), that is, its x component is 0 and its y component is negative mg.

Using the triangle to the right we get: $$\vec{Ft} = \vec{Fg} * cos\theta = 0 * cos\theta *\hat{x} + -mg*cos\theta*\hat{y} $$

Which means that the tension force's x component would be zero, which obviosly is not right. So, my question is, where does my logic fail? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The equation $\vec{F}_{t} = \vec{F}_{g} \cos \theta$ is not true.  Such an equation would imply that $\vec{F}_t$ is just $\vec{F}_g$ scaled by a certain factor, meaning the vectors would be parallel.  Instead, you should write $|\vec{F}_t| = |\vec{F}_g| \cos \theta$ (with magnitudes of the forces).

Comment: Technically, $|F_t| > |F_g| \cos\theta$ most of the time, because the weight is forced to follow a curved path.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** On a more careful reading of the question I see the answer is already
in a comment: $F_t$ and $F_g$ are in different directions, so you cannot
simply multiply one by $\cos\theta$ to get the other.

---

The component of the tension force in the direction of motion is zero
because it is perpendicular to the direction of motion.

But the direction of motion is not $\hat x$ most of the time.
The direction of motion is constantly changing.

The gravitational force has two components, 
one parallel to the direction of motion and one perpendicular.
The perpendicular component usually does not quite cancel out the tension force, 
because a net perpendicular force is required in order to make the
weight follow a curved path.
But calculating that force is not particularly helpful in describing the
motion of the pendulum.
Only the component parallel to the direction of motion is really needed.

Comment: Thank you. You say the gravitational force's components is parallel respectivly perpendicular to the motion. Is that for convenience or is there some logical reason for why they are not expressed in $\hat{x}$ respectively $\hat{y}$ direction?

Comment: Choosing components virtually always depends on what problem you're trying to solve. If we choose to use $x$ and $y$ components, it's generally  due to convenience (somehow) rather than any logical reason.

Comment: @David K What force does make the bob go in its circular path. Is it the net force of centripetal force and $F gsin\theta$?

Comment: As already explained multiple times in regard to this question, expressions such as $F_g \sin\theta$ are misleading. What you wrote is _not_ a component of the gravitational force, because it goes straight down yet is not the correct $y$ component. There is a tangential force whose magnitude is $|F_g| \sin\theta$ and (when the bob's velocity is non-zero) there is net radial force toward the center of the circle.